# Configure GPIO in uboot BeagleBoneBlack

Tags: embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, u-boot

I want to configure Pin P8_09 on beaglebone as gpio LOW on power ON. I have compiled a custom uboot for that and have been able to set pin low. The problem is that the pin goes HIGH for few milli seconds before going LOW.

Have defined the pin as gpio low in spl_start_uboot() function in board.c.

```
int spl_start_uboot(void)
{
REQUEST_AND_CLR_GPIO1(GPIO_TEST_GP);
 printf("Setting GPIO");
  #ifdef CONFIG_SPL_SERIAL_SUPPORT
/* break into full u-boot on 'c' */
if (serial_tstc() && serial_getc() == 'c')
    return 1;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_SPL_ENV_SUPPORT
env_init();
env_load();
if (env_get_yesno("boot_os") != 1)
    return 1;
#endif

return 0;
 }
#endif
```

I want to set the pin as LOW on power ON without any delay.

Comment: Your code will only be reached after a few milliseconds. Is the GPIO really actively high or is it in input mode for those milli seconds? In the later case a pull down resistor would do the job.